# Improving My Chatbot?

Tags: javascript, chatbot

I've been following a YouTube tutorial on how to design your own chatbot for a few hours now and have found myself stuck. Everything is going fine except when I type something to the chatbot it responds to it but doesn't show the message that I've sent to it, also it only show the last message that the chatbot send to me`,` never any other messages from it or me. [Here is a JsFiddle of my chatbot so far](http://jsfiddle.net/3wySt/7/) Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to resolve the problem?

Comment: Hi Joshua, i've also made some simple chat bot take a look at the code on github http://denimf.github.io/Answer-bot/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you overwrite the current HTML of `#container` by calling `$().html` instead of `$().append`. You should call `$().append` to add values to the current HTML of the container without overwriting it. You should also add `<br>` after each attempt to change the HTML of the container to separate the messages by a new line.

Here's your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3wySt/10/

Javascript

```
var username = "";

function send_message(message){
    $("#container").append("<span class=&bot&><b>Chatbot:</b> </span>" + message + "<br>"); //Notice the .append instead of .html and the <br>
}

function get_username(){
    send_message("Hello, what is your name?");
}

function ai(message){
    if (username.length < 3){
        username = message;
        send_message("Nice to meet you " + username + ", how are you doing?");
    }
}

$(function(){

    get_username();

    $("#textbox").keypress(function(event){
        if ( event.which == 13){
            if ( $("#enter").prop("checked") ){

                $("#send").click();
                event.preventDefault();

            }

        }

    });

    $("#send").click(function(){

        var username = "<span class=&quot;username&quot;>You: </span>";

        var newMessage = $("#textbox").val();

        $("#textbox").val("");

        var prevState = $("#container").html();

        if (prevState.length > 3){
            prevState = prevState + "";
        }

        $("#container").html(prevState + username + newMessage + "<br>"); //Notice the <br>

        $("#container").scrollTop($("#container").prop("scrollHeight"));

        ai(newMessage);

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, one more small issue on the fifth message that is sent a random <br> appears. Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I've just tried the JSFiddle and that doesn't happen, even after the fifth message. Here's a screenshot of the output after sending 8 messages http://i.stack.imgur.com/8wfzx.png

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I've just checked Neil's answer and I think you are trying his JSFiddle instead. Mine is located at http://jsfiddle.net/3wySt/10/ . Sorry for confusing you!

Comment: Yes I was using Neil's JsFiddle, works fine now. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: You are more than welcome! Feel free to ask if you come across any other problem. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3wySt/9/

I have updated your fiddle, the problem was with the following function where it was replacing the entire html instead of appending to it:

```
function send_message(message){
    $("#container").html("<span class=&bot&><b>Chatbot:</b> </span>" + message);
}
```